# An image floating over another

Tags: canvas, gtk, cairo

I want to be able to dynamically place images over another image in my app, using Cairo or GTK functions. Imagine, for example, a sea in which the user places fish and sea animals: it will be like that.

How can I do this? If you don't know but remember any simple program or demo that does that, it will be also very welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [GtkDrawingArea](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html) and draw the images on it using [cairo](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Cairo-Interaction.html):

Example:

```c
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

cairo_surface_t * sea_surface;
cairo_surface_t * fish_surface;

gboolean on_expose_event(GtkWidget * widget, GdkEventExpose * event, gpointer data) {
    // Create the cairo instance.
    cairo_t * cr = gdk_cairo_create(widget->window);
    // Draw the sea background.
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, sea_surface, 0.0, 0.0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    // Draw the fish.
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, fish_surface, 50.0, 50.0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    // Destroy the cairo instance.
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // Load images.
    sea_surface = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("sea.png");
    fish_surface = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png("fish.png");

    // Create window.
    GtkWidget * window;
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 320, 240);  

    // Create drawing area where we're going to draw our images.
    GtkWidget * drawing_area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(drawing_area), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(on_expose_event), NULL);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), drawing_area);

    // Show window and start gtk main loop.
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();

    // Clean-up.
    cairo_surface_destroy(fish_surface);
    cairo_surface_destroy(sea_surface);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile it on linux use:

```
gcc -Wall -g images.c -o images `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

---

Documentation:

- http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html
- http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Cairo-Interaction.html
- http://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-t.html

Examples:

- http://www.tortall.net/mu/wiki/PyGTKCairoTutorial
- http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/cairographicstutorial/cairoimages/

---

EDIT: If you need to be able to do this from Java, you can use [java-gnome](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/) which provides bindings for both GTK and [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/cairo-java/).

Comment: It's easy to draw the elements. It's much less easy dynamically placing and moving them, which is the work of a canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/), for details use the clutter examples, they are pretty nice.

**Edit:**

If you can not use clutter, you may have a look at [cairo](http://cairographics.org/) which also has some neat examples on the given homepage

Comment: Clutter is written for Gtk+ http://git.clutter-project.org/cgit.cgi?url=clutter-gtk/tree/README or just read the about part where it clearly says gtk+ embedded http://www.clutter-project.org/about

Comment: I meant in "pure" gtk, as I'm using GTK's bindings to Java and the Java interoperability of Clojure to code in this latter language, but now I see that there are Java bindings to Clutter, as well. Do you have any idea on how complete they are?

Comment: According to ebassi on #clutter@irc.gnome.org, "they are basically abandoned :-/". Thanks for the answer, but I'll have to do it in another way.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [GtkDrawingArea](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/2.21/GtkDrawingArea.html) with its [Gdk drawing primitives](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/stable/gdk-Drawing-Primitives.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to use a canvas like [goocanvas](http://live.gnome.org/GooCanvas), which is made to work with GTK and draw with cairo. However, it seems it currently only has bindings for C++ and python, so if you're using java, you'll have to find something else...